# Query In MongoDb while Insertion

Tags: mongodb

I use a function insertOne to insert an object. I have place correct colon and also correct commas then why this error come. Thanks in Advance.
This is my code

```
db.items.insertOne({Name:"Oppo",Price:"45000",Ritems:"345",Sold:"45","Rating:"3.5",once"twos"})
```

Error is this

```
uncaught exception: SyntaxError: missing : after property id :
@(shell):1:78
>
```

Comment: Why do you've `once"twos"` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your "" are misplaced. I think this way would be better ??

```
db.items.insertOne({Name:"Oppo",Price:"45000",Ritems:"345",Sold:"45",Rating:"3.5",once:"twos"})
```

Also the error message is telling you about the Id column, you should check if you need to set it yourself or if your database has an auto-increment ID.